# password_verify works in PHP 7.4 but doesn't work in PHP 8.2

Tags: php

I have two docker containers, one has PHP 8.2.3, another one PHP 7.4.30.

Plus, I have database with existing password hashes (that were originally created by Yii2 framework, using password password_hash, in unknown environment).

I made test.php, where I outputted two things:

```
var_dump(password_get_info('$2a$07$6c2eb62b00df224f3d20$.qzdiDRZejMnGytXWsA7Jid7RpWazDc6'))
```

and

```
var_dump(password_verify('password', '$2a$07$6c2eb62b00df224f3d20$.qzdiDRZejMnGytXWsA7Jid7RpWazDc6'))
```

**In PHP 7.4 the results are:**

```
array(3) {
  ["algo"]=>
  NULL
  ["algoName"]=>
  string(7) "unknown"
  ["options"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

And

```
bool(true)
```

**While in PHP 8.2:**

```
array(3) {
  ["algo"]=>
  NULL
  ["algoName"]=>
  string(7) "unknown"
  ["options"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

And

```
bool(false)
```

I know that different hashing algorithms might have been used. But the hashing algorithm should be specified (and thus identified) in the hash itself.

Plus, both engines don't know the algo. However, PHP 7.4 is able to verify the password.

Why this happens?

From the docs:

> Note that password_hash() returns the algorithm, cost and salt as part
> of the returned hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to
> verify the hash is included in it. This allows the verify function to
> verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or

Comment: FWIW, seems to be a bug specifically in that PHP version (and two others): https://3v4l.org/aJlhb

Comment: What a... oh, thatnk you so much. It's unbelievable. How come? Since it's a minor version. Super weird

Comment: Probably specifically related to this fix: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81744

Comment: Though I can't really find the actual code change related to that, it's the only relevant change in these affected versions: https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php#8.2.3, https://www.php.net/archive/2023.php#2023-02-14-3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've been affected by [this fix](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php#8.2.3):

> Malformatted BCrypt hashes that include a `$` within their salt part will trigger a buffer overread and may erroneously validate any password as valid.
>
> [..]
>
> The “PHP Hack” exists since the very first version of PHP’s own `crypt_blowfish` implementation and no clear reasoning is given for its existence in the commentary or commit history. In any case such a hash is not a valid BCrypt hash and it is not generated by `password_hash()`, which is the recommended password hashing API in PHP.
>
> While this technically might break backwards compatibility with existing users, the fact that these hashes are never generated by `password_hash()`, are not accepted by other implementations of BCrypt and introduce possible security vulnerabilities in applications, they should be rejected in every supported PHP version.
>
> https://github.com/php/php-src/security/advisories/GHSA-7fj2-8x79-rjf4

The emphasis here being on the fact that your hash is apparently technically invalid to begin with and should never have existed at all.

Comment: I remember that earlier versions of password_hash() allowed user-supplied salt. So I bet it should be the case here.

Comment: Might be indeed. So far I found out that the hash was hardcoded in database migration, assuming it's hash for "password". But how the hash was generated - nobody knows. Good news are that it's only for dev environment. First time in my life I stumble upon a bug after a minor version update, right before I installed a new docker container. Before 14 Feb I wouldn't encounter it :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense As the author of that advisory: Nope, password_hash never could emit a malformed hash, even with a user-supplied salt. In this case it's also easy to see that the hash was not emitted by password_hash, because of the $2a$ prefix, instead of $2y$. The hash was likely created by directly invoking crypt().